# ways to destruct object properties from nested array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this:

```
 const arr = [{name: 'mm', status: 200, response: {size: 1173, code: 0, data: {image: 'aa.png', abs_image: 'fwefwesa.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200,response: {size: 1133, code: 0, data: {image: 'bb.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200, response: {size: 1133, code: 0,data: {image: 'cc.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}}]
```

Are there any ways that I can use to destruct  `image`  property from `arr`, from which I will get an array of `['aa.jpg', 'bb.jpg', 'cc.jpg']`. I don't want to loop the array.

Comment: Without looping it's not possible.

Comment: one weird solution is to convert object to JSON string and then extract images with regex on that string :P

Comment: "_I don't want to loop the array_" Why not? That's what the loops are for, they are making your life easy. Alternatively you could hardcode every value into your image array, but that would be more or less you know what ...

Comment: fine, I just want to try if it is possible to do that using ES6 destructing or spread.Anyway, thanks guys.Seems that I have to loop it.

Comment: There you go: `const result = []; [{response: {data: {image: arr[0]}}}, {response: {data: {image: arr[1]}}}, {response: {data: {image: arr[2]}}}] = arr;` Moral of the story: destructuring is not the solution to all problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageArray = arr.map(elem => elem.response.data.image)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get array of values `image` by using only array destructuring, you can only get variable form single elements. To get the array you would have to do something like:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'mm', status: 200, response: {size: 1173, code: 0, data: {image: 'aa.png', abs_image: 'fwefwesa.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200,response: {size: 1133, code: 0, data: {image: 'bb.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200, response: {size: 1133, code: 0,data: {image: 'cc.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}}]

const [ {response: { data: { image } } }, {response: { data: { image: image2 } } }, {response: { data: { image: image3 } } }] = arr;
console.log([image, image2, image3]);
```

which does make litte sense. Instead you can do call map on that array, with or without parameter destructurization:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'mm', status: 200, response: {size: 1173, code: 0, data: {image: 'aa.png', abs_image: 'fwefwesa.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200,response: {size: 1133, code: 0, data: {image: 'bb.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}},{name: 'gg', status: 200, response: {size: 1133, code: 0,data: {image: 'cc.png', abs_image: 'fwefwerwea.jpg'}}}]

const imageArr = arr.map(({ response: { data: { image }}}) => image);
const imageArr2 = arr.map((item) => item.response.data.image);
console.log(imageArr);
console.log(imageArr2);
```